# Probability of largest order statistic greater than or equal to the second largest order statistic

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Given random variables $X_1, X_2..., X_n$ that are iid from uniform $[0,1]$, the [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, ..., X_{(n)}$ are also random variables, defined by sorting the values (realizations) of $X_1, ..., X_n$ in increasing order. Additionally, we have $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$ that are iid from uniform $[0,1]$ as well, and $Y_{(1)}, Y_{(2)}, ..., Y_{(n)}$ are defined similarly.

I want to compute the probability that $X_{(n)}$ (i.e., largest number) is greater than or equal to $Y_{(n-1)}$ (i.e., second largest number). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), we know that the PDF for $X_{(n)} \sim \beta(n, 1)$ is $f(x) = n x^{n-1}$; and the PDF for $Y_{(n-1)} \sim \beta(n-1, 2)$ is $f(y) = n(n-1)y^{n-2}(1-y)$. To compute $Pr(X_{(n)} \ge Y_{(n-1)})$. I have the follower two methods, which lead to different answers and I am not sure which part is wrong.

Method 1: $$Pr(X_{(n)} \ge Y_{(n-1)}) = \int_0^1 n x^{n-1} \int_0^x n(n-1)y^{n-2}(1-y) \, dy dx = \frac{3n-1}{4n-2}.$$

Method 2: I define random variable $Z = X_{(n)} - Y_{(n-1)}$, and according to Wikipedia

> Using the above formulas, one can derive the distribution of the range of the order statistics, that is the distribution of $X_{(k)} - X_{(j)}$ for $n \ge k > j \ge 1$ also forms a beta distribution $\beta(k-j, n-(k-j)+1)$.

Therefore, when $k=n$ and $j=n-1$, we have $Z \sim \beta(1, n)$ and $Pr(Z \ge 0) = 1$ which means $X_{(n)} \ge Y_{(n-1)}$ with probability $1$?

I am not sure which part goes wrong and which method has the correct answer... One concern I have with Method 1 is that this method ([Expression for one random variable greater than another random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308490/expression-for-one-random-variable-greater-than-another-random-variable)) seems to be used to compute $X_{(n)} > Y_{(n-1)}$ instead of $\ge$, could this be the problem?

Comment: The second method applies to order statistics of the same sample; hence the largest will exceed the second largest with probability 1. As for the first method - the events differ only by the set $X_{(n)} = Y_{(n-1)}$, which is a null set as both RVs have continuous distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So if I understand correctly, the answer from method 1 is right?

Comment: The method is correct - I haven't checked the calculations :-)